# /proc/cmdline does not updated with update-grub

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am testing kdump functionality based on a ubuntu distribution(ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64), and found that with the following step, the /proc/cmdline does not get updated:

1: modify /etc/default/grub[1]

2: sudo update-grub

3: reboot

After a reboot, cat /proc/cmdline[3] does not have what I have changed in /etc/default/grub, while the boot cmdline in /boot/grub/grub.cfg[2] do show what I have changed.

Any expert have some idea? Thanks a lot

---

[1]manually modified in /etc/defaut/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash *foo=bar crashkernel=256M*"

[2]automatically updated grub.cfg

/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=9e93b3d1-2859-473c-9c1f-204c2bb4e4f5 ro  quiet splash *foo=bar crashkernel=256M* $vt_handoff

[3]cat /proc/cmdline

eric@eric-test-kdump:~$ cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=9e93b3d1-2859-473c-9c1f-204c2bb4e4f5 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7

Comment: Found an exactly same issue as the following link and not get answered yet...
https://askubuntu.com/questions/898640/how-to-update-grub-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-through-maas-with-global-kernel

Comment: maybe you had installed grub-legacy by mistake, i saw, today apt install grub installed it in debian 10, and i had similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, are you also on a proxmox KVM? Modified the crashkernel config, ran grub-update and rebooted, still the /proc/cmdline stay's the same.

I called a reset from the proxmox interface and it was updated after that.

Comment: Please don't add *"Me too"* as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](//stackoverflow.com$/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you're interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a [comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), or start a [bounty](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) once you have enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 1):

Running Proxmox V6.1, I solve this issue by changing the content of:

/etc/kernel/cmdline

and then pushing the change with:

`pve-efiboot-tool refresh`

Answer (score 0):

Did you reboot?  Changes to the GRUB configuration do nothing until a reboot activates them.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the grub config is not updated is because the sudo update-grub command is outputting the changed file to stdout. You need to update the file in /boot with the -o flag.

```
sudo update-grub -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: but usually it works without that flag. when it may be not working?